# fastest way to compare two lists of strings in C#

Tags: c#, performance, string-comparison

I'm trying to compare two lists of type strings using equal method. Storing the two columns in two different arrays.

Is there any fast method to do the same and also since in two lists the number of entries can be large, so I need to efficient method for doing so.

I need to fetch the two list values from some table. Will an array be good idea to hold the values or some other structure need to use?

Comment: If you don't have repeatable values in the columns you can hold these values in the `HashSet<String>`; if there're repeatable values — Dictionary<String, int>. Hashbased collection are more efficient than arrays/lists in your problem

Comment: @ Dmitry Bychenko - values in both columns have repeatable values.

Comment: You have a database, can't you just do the comparison in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the speed is all your concern you can use `Dictionary` instead of `Lists/Arrays` when fetching the data

```
// Key (string) - String value
// Value (int)  - repeat count
Dictionary<String, int> values = new Dictionary<String, int>();

// Fill values: adding up v1, removing v2
using (IDataReader reader = myQuery.ExecuteReader()) {
  while (reader.Read()) {
    //TODO: put here the right reader index
    String v1 = reader[1].ReadString();
    String v2 = reader[2].ReadString(); 

    int repeatCount;

    if (values.TryGetValue(v1, out repeatCount)) 
      values[v1] = repeatCount + 1;
    else 
      values[v1] = 1;

    if (values.TryGetValue(v2, out repeatCount))
      values[v2] = repeatCount - 1;
    else 
      values[v2] = -1;
  }
}

// Select out the keys with positive values (where repeat count > 0)
List<String> result = values
  .Where(pair => pair.Value > 0)
  .Select(pair => pair.Key)
  .ToList();
```

However, Linq solution

```
  List<String> result = List1.Except(List2).ToList();
```

is much more consize

Answer (score 3):

By using [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) LINQ extension method,

```
List<string> resultList =  SecondList.Except(FirstList).ToList();
```

Comment: is this the fastest way.. even if size of list grows to some 1000 or more ?

Comment: 1000 is not the big. Do you want to check if they are different? If so, use IEnumerable + count to save some iterations - but I don't think that will have a big influence since 1000 values is practically nothing..

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) function for comparing two lists. Something like this:

```
List<string> result = list1.Except(list2).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 List<string> resultList =  SecondList.Except(FirstList).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr1 = new string [] { "b1", "b3"};
var arr2 = new string [] { "b1", "b2"};

arr1.SequenceEqual(arr2);
```